# How to create Mobile API's in OSCommerce?

Tags: oscommerce

I want to create Mobile App using my os commerce store. Is there any extension for API's integration in OS Commerce.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any extension API that exists as you describe.

There is a responsive version of OSCommerce;

[GitHub](https://github.com/gburton/Responsive-osCommerce)

Maybe you could consider upgrading to that version as it uses bootstrap which is 'mobile first'.

Bootstrap offers a quick professional solution to designing sites for all display sizes, without the need for multiple websites.